# Should we add an [OEIS] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have *lots* of challenges related to the OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences).

- Challenges that are integrated with the OEIS

  - [Evolution of OEIS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49223/31716)
  - [Find the program that prints this integer sequence (Cops' thread)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77419/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-cops-thread)
  - [Extending OEIS: Counting Diamond Tilings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51266/31716)
- Challenges that are about producing a sequence from the OEIS

  - [Spiral Permutation Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70802/31716)
  - [Motzkin Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66851/31716)
  - [Sum the odd square numbers less than N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78141/31716)
  - [Print the Super Collatz numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71000/print-the-super-collatz-numbers)

This is just a fraction of the number of challenges we actually have on the subject. For example, [this search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=Oeis+is%3Aq) shows 75 questions with "OEIS" somewhere in the body.

Should we add a tag for this? I see only two potential downsides:

1. It's a little bit of a meta-tag. Can you be an expert in the OEIS? To be fair, most of our tags that aren't a winning criteria are a little bit meta.
2. It doesn't add a whole lot on top of the already existing [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) tag. Maybe it should be a synonym instead?

---

What does meta think? Could this tag contribute anything useful?